# Connexion pronunciation & verb

Tags: verbs, nouns, word-usage, pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling

> Connexion is the original and variant spelling of "connection", common until at least the 19th century, and still occasionally used in British English (it was the house style of The Times of London as recently as the 1980s). It is derived from the Latin connexio, hence the spelling, unlike most words ending in "-ction" which are derived from Latin words ending in "-ctio" (e.g. "protection" from protectio).

1) How do we pronounce the above word, *connexion*?

Like connection, its successor can be pronounced as con-nek-shun, how can we pronounce *connexion*? perhaps con-neg-zhun? And if it is the same as *connection*, then why so? the spelling and origins are different.

2) How do we pronounce its verb, *connex*? (But is connex even the verb of connexion?)

Like connection's *connect* can be pronounced as con-nekt, how can we pronounce *connex*? can it be con-neks? or simply con-nekt, but there is no sound of *k* or *t* in the spelling.

Lastly, as British English user, is it acceptable to use this word as a substitute to *connection* in formal English or is it completely taken over by *connection*?

Comment: See also [*complexion*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/complexion) and [*reflexion*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/reflexion?s=t).

Comment: @PeterShor Yeah when I was reading about connex I also found those two, reflexion is like connexion and complexion is more common than complection.. :D

Comment: (1) /kə'nɛkʃən/. (2) the verb is _connect_, pronounced /kə'nɛkt/.

Comment: "is connex even the verb of connexion?" No, it isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just two spellings of the same word (one word = one pronunciation). From OED...

> The earlier English lexicographers, including Bailey, Johnson, Walker, Todd, Crabb, recognize connexion only. Connection appears in Webster (1828) who says ‘For the sake of regular analogy, I have inserted Connection as the derivative of the English connect , and would discard connexion ’. This preference has been followed by other dictionaries in U.S. Latham would differentiate the two spellings and use connexion only in senses 5 – 8 Connexion is the official and invariable spelling in sense 8, and was used in all senses by the majority of writers (or printers) in England until the mid-20th cent., when connection became more usual.
>   ...
>   5: A personal relation of intercourse, intimacy, common interest, or action. Often with pl.
>   6: Relationship by family ties, as marriage or distant consanguinity. Often with 'a' and pl.
>   7: A body, or circle of persons connected together, or with whom one is connected...
>   8: Used by Wesley of those associated or connected with him in religious work and aims; thence it gradually became with the Wesleyans equivalent to ‘religious society’ or ‘denomination’, and is used also by other Methodist associations and bodies which have sprung from them.
>   ...

I know that's a lot of cut & paste, but I can't see anything to add, cut, or phrase better. Oh - except a personal opinion: *Don't use it today in formal contexts - it'll probably be thought "vulgar".*

Comment: Oh , ok thanks main query was if their pronunciations were different despite being same words.

Comment: Same pronunciation. From OED: connexion, connection

(kəˈnɛkʃən)